# pytorch previous version installation conflict in my local machine

Tags: python-2.7, pytorch, environment-variables, conda, torchvision

I am trying to install PyTorch and Torchvision with the following conda command in python 2.7 environment

> conda install pytorch==1.1.0 torchvision==0.3.0 -c pytorch

But getting this error,

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - torchvision==0.3.0 -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=2.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package vs2008_runtime conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> vc=9 -> vs2008_runtime[version='>=9.0.30729.1,<10.0a0']
pytorch==1.1.0 -> ninja -> vs2008_runtime
python=2.7 -> vs2008_runtime

Package zlib conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> sqlite[version='>=3.30.1,<4.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
torchvision==0.3.0 -> pillow[version='>=4.1.1'] -> zlib[version='1.2.*|1.2.11|1.2.11.*|>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|1.2.8']
```

My conda list for the specific python 2.7 environment is

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2021.1.19            haa95532_0
certifi                   2020.6.20          pyhd3eb1b0_3
pip                       19.3.1                   py27_0
python                    2.7.18               hfb89ab9_0
setuptools                44.0.0                   py27_0
sqlite                    3.30.1               h0c8e037_0
vc                        9                    h7299396_1
vs2008_runtime            9.00.30729.1         hfaea7d5_1
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wincertstore              0.2              py27hf04cefb_0
```

I tried to upgrade sqlite to 3.33.0 but it is showing

> ## All requested packages already installed.

And when I tried to uninstall sqlite the whole python package for the environment is getting uninstalled.
Kindly someone helps me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyTorch never made a Windows build of those versions of PyTorch and TorchVision for Python 2.7. One can use `conda search` for this:

```bash
$ conda search 'pytorch[channel=pytorch,subdir=win-64,version=1.1]'
Loading channels: done
# Name     Version    Build                     Channel             
pytorch    1.1.0      py3.5_cuda100_cudnn7_1    pytorch             
pytorch    1.1.0      py3.5_cuda90_cudnn7_1     pytorch             
pytorch    1.1.0      py3.6_cuda100_cudnn7_1    pytorch             
pytorch    1.1.0      py3.6_cuda90_cudnn7_1     pytorch             
pytorch    1.1.0      py3.7_cuda100_cudnn7_1    pytorch             
pytorch    1.1.0      py3.7_cuda90_cudnn7_1     pytorch
```

At minimum you'd have to use Python 3.5, but if you're going to Python 3 and need those specific PyTorch versions, you may as well jump to Python 3.7.

```
conda create -n pytorch_1_1 -c pytorch python=3.7 pytorch=1.1 torchvision=0.3
```

Comment: Will it work on a Linux machine? python=3.7 pytorch=1.1 torchvision=0.3

Comment: Yes, both 3.7 and 2.7 have PyTorch builds for Linux and OS X. Just Windows that they seemed to selectively exclude. Try `conda search 'pytorch[channel=pytorch,subdir=linux-64,version=1.1]'`